# result cannot delivered

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

This app for testing use Builtin camera in android ??? 
what is the error in my code which cause this error

i am starting camera and capture a photo then i want to display it in imageView

i found that the photo stored in SDcard but cannot use it in onActivityResult method

```
package com.world.hello;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(
                        "/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMAG.jpg")));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 100) {
                Log.d("Image", data.getData().toString());
//              ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//              iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData().toString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why this error ??

```
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.world.hello/com.world.hello.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at com.world.hello.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:40)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
05-24 17:19:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(4759):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Does your parent folder exist already?

Comment: yes the captured photo stored already in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Log.d("Image", data.getData().toString());
```

You don't need to get the data then. You already know the location of the file that the image is saved to. Use that directly.